Thermal resistance from junction to case vs junction to ambient
I have been trying to measure junction temperature of some ICs in a PCB board and their IC packaging vary between TO-252, DDPAK and TSOT26 types. For the TO-252, DDPAK packages there is exposed copper on the board where the ICs sit, but other than that none of ICs have additional heatsink in the board, they are just directly soldered on the PCB board.
To calculate the junction temperature, I have measured the case temperature (with a thermal camera), calculated power dissipation within the IC, and then used the following formula- Tjunction=Tcase+ ƟJC*PD , (here, PD= power dissipation, and ƟJC stands for thermal resistance from junction to case). Is that a valid way to calculate junction temperature?
I am mainly confused because the datasheets usually provide another thermal resistance parameter- thermal resistance from junction to ambient, ƟJA. Should I have used the ƟJA parameter instead? With that parameter I could have used the following equation to calculate junction temperature- Tjunction=Tambient+ ƟJA*PD.
So, which thermal parameter (ƟJA vs ƟJC) should I use to calculate junction temperature of an IC and why should we choose one over the other?
Thank you for your comments and insights.

You can do both. The datasheet values are generally provided by taking Tambient as 25 degree celsius.

  
    
      
        
          
            
              T
              
                JUNCTION
              
            
            =
            
              T
              
                CASE
              
            
            +
            
              θ
              
                JC
              
            
            ×
            Power
          
        
      
    
  

and

  
    
      
        
          
            
              T
              
                JUNCTION
              
            
            =
            
              T
              
                AMBIENT
              
            
            +
            
              θ
              
                JA
              
            
            ×
            Power
          
        
      
    
  



Is that a valid way to calculate junction temperature?
Yes, but that isn't as good as using something like an infinite thermal heatsink that is controlled at a specific temperature. So you will have also a bit of the case thermal resistance in with the package thermal resistance.

If you wanted to measure only the package thermal resistance, you'd need a good heatsink, preferably actively cooled. You would probably also want to put some kind of insulator or something to reduce the contribution of the air wicking away heat.

Junction to ambient thermal resistance is the heat lost to the air, so the component would need to be in the air, and then you could measure how much heat is lost to the air.
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra953d/spra953d.pdf?ts=1727125363330
